# Google Paly sign in Does not work in Android

Tags: android, google-play

I am implementing google play sing in, but it does not work

I follow the developer document to implement it but still, it does not work

Comment: Try to describe what you tried, what you expected and what you got. There is no information in your question to help you other way than by the answer "You're doing something wrong"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step1 : Set up the app in the Google Play Console

1. Create a new app .
2. Then, in your app-level build.gradle file, declare Google Play services as a 
   dependency:

   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
3. Sign in to Google Play Console. . If you haven't registered for the
   Google Play Console before, it will prompt you to register. Add your
   app to [Google play console](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/sl/pwd?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fadmin.google.com%2Fgoogle.com%2FServiceNotAllowed%3Fservice%3Dandroiddeveloper%26continue%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fapps%2Fpublish%2F%2523&service=CPanel&skipvpage=true&passive=3600&authuser=0&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin)
4. Add your app to Google play console .

   a. Open the Game Services page, then click the **Add New Game** button on 
         the left.

   b. Since  you are creating from scratch, select the tab **I don't use any 
         Google APIs in my game yet** . Enter your app name and select  a 
         category, and then click the **Continue** button.

   c. In the Detail form Only the display name  and description are required 
         for testing. The other fields must be filled out before you can publish 
         your game.

   d. Click save .

   e. Open the page **Liked apps** on the right  and click  **Android**  and 
         enter the name of the app and the package name in the relevant field.

   f. Enable the appropriate multiplayer settings, **real-time or turn- 
         based**.

   g. Select anti privacy on  and Click save and continue.

   h. Now click the **Authorize your app now** button .

   i. In the **Package name** field, enter your package name  and  enter you 
         app  SHA1 in the **Signing certificate fingerprint (SHA1)** field . and 
         Click **Confirm**.

   j. After you click the **Confirm**  button, you should see your new client 
         ID for this application. Copy and paste it in a safe place .

   k. Make sure that the account you intend to sign in with (the account on 
         the test device) is listed as a tester in the project on your Developer 
         Console setup (check the list in the "Testing" section)

Step 2: Make the following changers in your app

1. In your manifest file under application tag add then following meta tag and 
     replace “**YOUR APPID**” with the client Id. That you got when you authorize 
     your application in The Google play console.
2. To add  standard Google sign-in button in your app, Include a 
    ***com.google.android .gms.common .SignIn Button*** the main activity 
    layout.
3. Initiate your sing in Button in On Create method of the Activity.

   *signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button)*
4. When the user click on the sign in button . The following code snip sends the 
    sign in intend .

   signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   ```
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
         startSignInIntent();
         }
      });
   ```
5. The following code snip shows you how to initialize the  startsignin()
    Method

   private void startSignInIntent() {

   ```
   GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
   GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
   Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
   startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
      }
   ```
6. In the onActivityResult() callback, handle the result from the returned
    Intent.

   ```
    **@Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
     data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
         GoogleSignInResult result =  
         Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
       if (result.isSuccess()) {
          GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
      } else {
          String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
          if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
              message = getString(R.string.signin_other_error);
          }
          new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message)
                  .setNeutralButton("Login Fail", null).show();
      }
   ```

   }
     }**