# Google Play Referrer Api

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play-services

I want to integrate google play referrer api, but I am not able get proper understanding after reading doc. I also want to know what data can I fetch and how can I test my App after integration.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling.) you should follow to integrate google play services
if you find any difficulties I have explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56150807/google-paly-sign-in-does-not-work-in-android/56154149#56154149) step by step , I hope this will guide to integrate google play services

Comment: I guess `Play Referrer API` & `Google Play Services` are two different things.